# Is firebase production ready for 100% offline app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are developing an app(iOS & Android) for managing personal finance. According to our market research, 90% of our users would not prefer to sync data online.

Also we would allow offline users to take data backup offline and restore it later as per requirements. In only 10% cases, active syncing with server is desirable.

Is firebase good choice for our use case?

Kindly suggest other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase apps work great offline and it has several features to make the experience even better. Enabling disk persistence allows your app to keep all of its states even after an app restart. it provides several tools for monitoring presence and connectivity state.

like

1. Disk Persistence
2. Querying Data Offline
3. Handling Transactions Offline

NOTE: Transactions are not persisted across app restarts. Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across app restarts. So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being committed to your Firebase Realtime Database. To provide the best user experience, your app should show that a transaction has not been saved into your { firebase_database} yet, or make sure your app remembers them manually and executes them again after an app restart.

NOTE: The Firebase Realtime Database has many features for dealing with offline scenarios and network connectivity. The rest of this guide applies to your app whether or not you have persistence enabled.

There are other sources also have a look 
[Link](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-closest-open-source-alternative-to-Firebase)